# Sharing mac clipboard with vim inside terminal

Tags: terminal, macvim

I use vim inside terminal and trying to share the mac clipboard with vim.

Compiled vim with xterm_clipboard support and installed XQuartz.

```
MacBook-Air:web-ui nagakirank$ vim --version | grep xterm_clipboard
+xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save

Nagas-MacBook-Air:web-ui nagakirank$ echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-ltuLWk/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

But,am not able to get Mac clipboard content inside vim using "+" register "+y.

Now,clueless on why it's not working..Need pointers on how to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try building Vim 7.3 with the `clipboard` feature enabled. Starting in Vim 7.3, `+clipboard` uses the OS X pasteboard directly (via the `*` or `+` register, as you expected).

It probably is possible to use `+xterm_clipboard` with an X server configured to convert X’s selection to and from the OS X pasteboard, but it would probably be more problematic than the direct `+clipboard` solution.

---

As an example, the MacPorts build of the `vim` port that I have currently installed (`vim @7.3.661_0+huge+perl+python27+ruby+tcl`) has `+clipboard`, `-xterm_clipboard`, and can access the pasteboard through `*` and `+`.

Also, if you happen to be running Vim inside *tmux* you will probably need [my wrapper program](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/) to reenable pasteboard access inside *tmux* sessions; this only applies to `+clipboard` access: X-mediated access might still work OK—as long as you keep DISPLAY updated—but still seems unnecessarily cumbersome to me.

Comment: It's working fine when vim launched outside screen and problem is only with vim inside screen. Went through your post and found that screen installed via Ports has the patches to fix this. Installed screen via Ports and that solved the issue..Thanks..Haven't expected I would be able to solve this easily